# aws S3 how to show contents of file based on a pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cat

I would like to perform a simple

```
cat dir/file.OK.*
```

how can this be achieved in aws?

I came up with

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket-name/path/to/folder/ - --exclude="*" --include="R0.OK.*"
```

but this returns:

```
 download failed: *(the path)* to - An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found
```

Thank you for your help.

Additional detail: there is supposed to be only one file matching the pattern, so we could use that information. Anything else is allowed to (horribly) fail.

Edit - currently I am just executing an aws ls into a file, and then cp-ing every file piped into grep. Works, but a nuissance.

Comment: You are missing `--recursive` from your command, but there might be other issues as well

Comment: hi, yes I tried that but: "Streaming currently is only compatible with non-recursive cp commands"

Comment: I will use two steps then - aws ls , try to process that and cp that file.

Comment: Or `aws s3 cp` them to local disk, cat the resulting files, then delete them (as needed).

Comment: @jarmod actually that would probably not be slower, so yes... excellent Idea!
I would like to raise that to an answer but I cant

Comment: I can add an answer if it helps.

Comment: sure, ill then accept that , thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would consider an alternative to streaming the S3 content direct to stdout, which is to simply copy the files from S3 to local disk, which will allow you to use include/exclude/recursive, cat the files locally, and then simply delete the files afterwards.